# What is returned as a result of calling makeFancy("JAVA")?

Tags: java

just updated with working code, special thanks to BraveMaster

public class methods {

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.println(makeFancy("JAVA"));
}
public static String makeFancy(String s) {
    if (s.length() == 0) {
        return "*";
    }
    return "*" + s.substring(0,1) + makeFancy(s.substring(0, s.length()-1));
}
```

Comment: What was the result when you tried it?

Comment: Your question is basically just "what happens when I run this". Why don't you ... you know, run this? Then you'll see.

Comment: Hi, thanks for reaching out. Unfortunately, IntelliJ is not displaying an output. My code does not seem to have any technical issues, however.

Comment: Do you just call `makeFancy("JAVA")` as the body of your main? Then the code will execute, but the return value will be ignored. Try putting in something like `System.out.println(makeFancy("JAVA"));`

Comment: If nothing happens then the answer to your question is "nothing happens". If you **want** something else to happen, post a [mre] and explain what you were trying to accomplish.

Comment: Thanks, I received output.

Comment: I just edited my code so it could compile. Thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried your code in [compilejava.net](https://www.compilejava.net/), and the result was

```
*J*J*J*J*
```

Full source code is here:

```
// one class needs to have a main() method
public class HelloWorld
{
  // arguments are passed using the text field below this editor
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    System.out.println(makeFancy("JAVA"));
  }

  public static String makeFancy(String s) {
    if (s.length() == 0) {
        return "*";
    }
    return "*" + s.substring(0,1) + makeFancy(s.substring(0, s.length()-1));
}

}
```

PS: The quality of your question is not very high. If you have a problem with your IDE, you can simply try your code in online sandboxes like this one :)

Comment: Thanks so much :) it was a big help, my code actually wasn't compiling in IntelliJ and I needed this. Thank you once again.

Comment: Don't forget to upvote and approve my answer! :)

Comment: Yes, I just did. It wasn't a problem. Thanks:)